# How to fix Null pointer exception Firebase Auth

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebaseui

I am trying to Retrieve and display the user name from the current authenticated user with FirebaseAuth but the app crash with a NullPointerException

I tryed to display the the user.getDisplayName() in the consol and its not Null

```java
ImageView profilePicView = findViewById(R.id.profile_pic);
        TextView nameView = findViewById(R.id.name);
        TextView emailView = findViewById(R.id.email);

        FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        if (user != null) {
            if (user.getDisplayName() != null) {
                System.out.println("------------------------------user display name : " + user.getDisplayName());
                nameView.setText(user.getDisplayName());
            }

            if (user.getEmail() != null) {
                emailView.setText(user.getEmail());
            }

            if (user.getPhotoUrl() != null) {
                Glide.with(this)
                        .load(user.getPhotoUrl())
                        .into(profilePicView);
            }
        }
```

Here is the stack Error

```
I/System.out: ------------------------------user display name : Mohammed Elmahdi Bechlaghem
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.megadevbrain.ranahna, PID: 20913
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.megadevbrain.ranahna/com.megadevbrain.ranahna.Navigation}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3121)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3264)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1955)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7076)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:965)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
        at com.megadevbrain.ranahna.Navigation.onCreate(Navigation.java:52)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7327)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7318)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1275)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3101)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3264) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1955) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7076) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:965) 
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 20913 SIG: 9
Process 20913 terminated.
```

Comment: Make sure you have `testview` with id `name` in your `xml`. Or post your `xml` file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Null pointer try to say that your Textview is null. That can happen because the findviewbyid is not matching with the right one on your XML. Be sure your id matches your XML and the.Java java file

Comment: This was very helpful i was using a naviation drawer and did not "getHeaderView(0).findViewById(R.id.profile_pic)" , totaly missed it thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

you must use Thread in your method that calls the object.

Answer (score 0):

Either 'nameView' or 'emailView' variable is null. Please check R.id.name and R.id.email are valid TextView in current view xml.